# Why are the strings from the text file not being added to my array of strings?

Tags: c++, hash, find

I have a program that is supposed to take a Dictionary.txt-which has 200 separate lines with one string per line- and hash each string into an array. Then I take a user inputted string and attempt to find this string within my newly filled array. The program is using a modulo hash function to get an array index for each string, and is supposed to read the .txt file line by line. As of right now, the program executes with no errors but the array is completely empty after attempting to read in the strings.

I have tried the getline function as well as file >> input.

***EDIT***: My file was not opening correctly, so I replaced the url in my file.open() method to the C:/ direct url instead of using the one I included in my Visual Studio project.

```
int wordFinder(fstream& file, string word) {
    string Table[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        //modulo hashing using size of array
        int index = i % 200;
        //collision
        if (!(Table[index].empty())) {
            int count = 0;
            do {
                index = (index + 1) % 200;
                count++;
            } while ((!(Table[index].empty())) && (count < 200));//while the current position is occupied and count is less than the size of the array
            getline(file, Table[index], '\n');//take string from file and put it into the table array
            cout << "Collision " << Table[index]<< endl;
        }
        //no collision
        else {
            cout << "No Collision " << Table[index]<<index<< endl;
            getline(file, Table[index], '\n');//take string from file and put it into the table array
        }
    }
    //find string if in array
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        if (Table[i].compare(word) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //print table values
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        cout << Table[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is for the program to return 1 if the word is found, or 0 if not found. It should also print the array of values, each index having a separate word from the .txt file. As of now, the program always returns 0 because the array ends up completely empty, and therefore the program prints a bunch of whitespace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't say whether the program reports "Collision" or "No Collision", but either way you are calling `empty()` on uninitialized members of an array, which is UB. But more to the point, you are trying to do too many new things at once. Try something simpler: write code that reads one word from a file and puts it into a `string`. Once that works, try reading the word into the first element of a `string` array. Then two words. Once that much works, you can try this hashing trick (which makes no sense to me).

Comment: You probably should just delete the question. It won't really help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

My file was not opening correctly, so I replaced the url in my file.open() method to the C:/ direct url instead of using the one I included in my Visual Studio project. It worked after I made this change.